# How do I get three.js to show up in browser?

Tags: javascript, three.js, typeerror

whenever I try to open and see my progress with three.js on my browser locally, it will not load and throws me this error,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

I'm new to three.js and been stuck for a while and haven't even really gotten started. I appreciate the help. If my first lines of the javascript file is: `import * as THREE from '/Users/16103/Desktop/three'`. Thank you!

Comment: Well, where is your HTML file located? Are you trying to load the HTML from the filesystem (e.g., "file://C:/Users/16103/Desktop/index.html")? Because that is unlikely to work, as module loading needs to happen over HTTP.

Comment: If you just want to get started playing with three.js, it's easiest to just import is via an HTML `<script>` tag.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. My html is located in a different folder than the three folder but they're both in my desktop folder. I also did add the <script> tag and if I follow the link in VScode it is connected properly. But when I try to copy the relative path into my browser or open it through five server, its a blank screen with that Type error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a demo with a cdn like this simple one taken from their samples. You can download the script from cdn locally.

```js
var camera, scene, renderer, geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.z = 500;
  scene.add(camera);

  geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200);
  material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

function render() {
  mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
  mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r54/three.js"></script>

<canvas style="margin-top:-200px"></canvas>
```